# matlab didn't find solution for polynomial

Tags: matlab, polynomials

I want to use Matlab to solve polynomial. So, I use `solve()` function.

Here's matlab code.

```
% variable
Cmin = 8;
N0 = 0;
B = 8;
P_s_max = 2;
P_r_max = 10;
h_sr = 1;
h_rd = 12;
h_sd = 1;
h_li = 3;

% polynomial
syms P_sr  P_rd
formula1 = (P_sr*h_sr)-(P_rd*h_li)*(2^(Cmin/B)-1)>=(2^(Cmin/B)-1)*N0;
formula2 = (P_rd*h_rd)-(P_sr*h_sd)*(2^(Cmin/B)-1)>=(2^(Cmin/B)-1)*N0;
formula3 = 0<=P_sr;
formula4 = P_sr<=P_s_max;
formula5 = 0<=P_rd;
formula6 = P_rd<=P_r_max;
sol = solve([formula1, formula2, formula3, formula4, formula5, formula6], [P_sr, P_rd]);

% solution
x = vpa(sol.P_sr, 4);
y = vpa(sol.P_rd, 4);
```

variable `formula` is my polynomial function which I want to solve.
variable `x` is 4 solution of `P_sr`.

But, I got `x = 0.0` and `y = 0.0`.
Actually, `P_sr` can be 0.4 and P_rd can be 0.3. How can I modify code?